# RobotFramework Convert minutes to hours

Tags: robotframework

Is there any built-in library keyword which converts minutes to hours in Robot framework? If not, How can I do that?

Eg:5 minutes = 0.0833333 hours

I'm new to Robot, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate). For example:

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example of converting minutes to hours
| | ${minutes}= | Set variable | 5
| | ${hours}= | Evaluate | ${minutes}/60.00
| | log to console | \nHours: ${hours}
```